# Export to CSV and Compress with GZIP in postgres

Tags: postgresql, backup, gzip, compression

I need to export a big table to csv file and compress it.

I can export it using COPY command from postgres like -

`COPY foo_table to '/tmp/foo_table.csv' delimiters',' CSV HEADER;`

And then can compress it using gzip like -

`gzip -c foo_table.csv > foo.gz`

The problem with this approach is, I need to create this intermediate csv file, which itself is huge, before I get my final compressed file.

Is there a way of export table in csv and compressing the file in one step?

Regards,
Sujit

Comment: If it doesn't necessarily have to be CSV, you could use pg_dump, as in: `pg_dump -Z 5`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The trick is to make `COPY` send its output to stdout, then pipe the output through gzip:

```
psql -c "COPY foo_table TO stdout DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER" \
    | gzip > foo_table.csv.gz
```

Comment: one may use pigz (multithreaded gzip) instead of gzip for faster compression. Usually gzip is the bottlneck.

Answer (score 15):

You can use directly, as per docs, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-copy.html

```
COPY foo_table to PROGRAM 'gzip > /tmp/foo_table.csv' delimiter ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: Typo correction `DELIMITER` with no trailing `S`: `COPY foo_table TO PROGRAM 'gzip > /tmp/foo_table.csv.gz' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ;`

Answer (score 9):

Expanding a bit on @Joey's answer, below adds support for a couple more features available in [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY).

```
psql -c "COPY \"Foo_table\" (column1, column2) TO stdout DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER" \
    | gzip > foo_table.csv.gz
```

If you have capital letters in your table name (woe be onto you), you need the `\"` before and after the table name.

The second thing I've added is column listing.

Also note from the docs:

> This operation is not as efficient as the SQL COPY command because all data must pass through the client/server connection. For large amounts of data the SQL command might be preferable.

Answer (score 3):

`PostgreSQL 13.4`

`psql` command `\copy` also works combined with `SELECT column_1, column_2, ...` and timestamp `date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S"` for filename dump.

```sql
\copy (SELECT id, column_1, column_2, ... FROM foo_table) \ 
TO PROGRAM 'gzip > ~/Downloads/foo_table_dump_`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S"`.csv.gz' \
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ;
```